# jsoup search elements for key words

Tags: java, jsoup

I was able to poll all the data I needed in Java using Jsoup and store it as elements and named that "links". I want to scan that for states for example California, Nevada, and Texas and increment the count by one each time one of them is listed in the polled data. I know that I would want to crate an int for each state, throw this in a while statement with a += and create 50 of these statements to scan for every state but how would I go about this? also is there a way to avoid typing that statement 50 times?

The code for the links is

```
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.cinemark.com/full-theatre-list").get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");  
}
```

The code i posted functions perfectly and gets me what I want, so i guess my question is how to i reference the elements i created and scan them for key words.

Please note that this is only a portion of the code so it will not run without setting up a path for jsoup. My question is not about the code I posted that is only there to give a general idea of the program.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs improvement. For example it would help if you describe your used data structures. Also try to come up with some code, or at least pseudo-code and ask specific questions about it. As such your question is too general.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that, if I post a screen shot can you explain to me what I would put for future use?

Comment: No screenshots please. A start would be to post the code that you wrote to collect the "links"

Comment: try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.cinemark.com/full-theatre-list").get();
   
   String title = doc.title();
   System.out.println("title : " + title);
   
   Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

Comment: let me know if there would be any more useful info i could provide

Comment: A posting of a much more decent attempt would be nice. It doesn't look like you've really tried yet. Please look at the [mcve] link to see the best type of code to post.

Comment: Consider using a `HashMap`.

Comment: The code i posted functions perfectly and gets me what I want, so i guess my question is how to i reference the elements i created and scan them for key words

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of a hashmap jyr

Comment: Page doesn't load for me, so your question should contain relevant parts of the html source code as well, because it might be simpler to sort the elements using more specific css selectors.

Comment: fred please refer to the last 2 sections in the initial post that code is only a small portion and will not run without several exceptions and creating a path for jsoup

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are pretty new to programming (in Java). One way of doing what you want to be doing looks like this:

1) Create a class StateCount like this:

```
private class StateCounter {
    public String name = "";
    public int count = 0;

    public StateCounter(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.count = 0;
    }
}
```

2) in your code

```
//create StateCounter instances in a list
List<StateCounter> statecounters = new ArrayList<StateCounter>();

statecounters.add(new StateCounter("Texas"));
statecounters.add(new StateCounter("Nevada"));
...

//when you have the links

for (Element link: links){
    for (StateCounter sc : statecounters){
        if (link.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining​("href", sc.name)){
            sc.count++;
        }
    }
}

//do whatever you need to do.
```

Of course you also could use a HashMap data structure to store the counts. It depends a little what you actually want to do with the counts.